# Mysql database close or not

Tags: php, mysql

I'll develop a website where there might be thousands of users using it **concurrently** with database features. In recent years I **never** closed my database connections in my apps. In this case, is it better to close database connection after running every query or shall just leave it open?

I know that exhausting the connection pool etc. happens if not closed but I tried to look for answers for particularly MySql but I was not very lucky.

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1, MySql with PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to close a connection manually. PHP will automatically close it for you at the end of the script's execution.

Comment: Or better yet, at the end of the connection variable's scope.